# Javascript onchange event. select/option html dropdown input

Tags: javascript, forms, addeventlistener

```
var inputDrop = document.createElement('select');
inputDrop.setAttribute("onchange", function test(){alert("test");});
form.appendChild(inputDrop);


var inputOpt1 = document.createElement('option');
inputOpt1.value="1";
inputOpt1.innerHTML="1";
inputDrop.appendChild(inputOpt1);

var inputOpt2 = document.createElement('option');
inputOpt2.value="2";
inputOpt2.innerHTML="2";
inputDrop.appendChild(inputOpt2);

form.appendChild(inputDrop);
```

I need to assign somekind of event handler to **select** dropdown input field with a number of options. I need to execute a function whenever a different option is selected. The above doesnt work and neither does **inputDrop.onchange="alert('test')";** not sure what im doing wrong here, please could someoneadvise?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pete. What you're looking for is something like

```
inputDrop.addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert("PETE'S TEST"); });
```

I put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate this working: http://jsfiddle.net/pbaXP/1/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working

```
inputDrop.onchange = function test(){alert("test");};
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C2c6e/)